# ModelForm Instance vs Initial

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm super new to Django, so bare with me. I'm trying to write a simple CRUD, using modelforms. In the update view, the form object initialization takes the arguments initial and instance, which confuses me. From django doc:

"As with regular forms, it’s possible to specify initial data for forms by specifying an initial parameter when instantiating the form. Initial values provided this way will override both initial values from the form field and values from an attached model instance."

Which confuses even more. I know my question isn't specific, but if someone could explain this and honestly, the background connection between the **model and modelforms** I would really appreciate it. Thanks y'all

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example from Django docs;

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

TITLE_CHOICES = [
    ('MR', 'Mr.'),
    ('MRS', 'Mrs.'),
    ('MS', 'Ms.'),
]

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'title', 'birth_date']
```

Your form -`AuthorForm` has information that `name` is string and it can't be greater than 100 characters. Because it's in your model -`Author`. Same for `title` and `birth_date`. `title` can't be greater than 3 characters and it must be one of the `MR`, `MRS` or `MS`.

You don't have to specify types, rules for form fields if you use model forms. Model forms can create forms quickly from your model and makes validations based on your model.

Let's assume you have an `author` instance which has `name` is `Joe`.

If you print `author.name`, it returns `Joe`.

`form = AuthorForm(initial={'name': 'Patrick'}, instance=author)`

If you print `form['name'].value()`, it returns `Patrick`, not `Joe`. It ignores `author`'s `name` value. You overrided it in your form. It could be Joe if you didn't pass `initial` parameter.

Comment: I see. But when I save the form, it will still update the author instance, right? i guess i dont fully understand what the form object is. i know i can print it in the html. but in this example, if i save the form, will the author instance get updated with name = Patrick?

Comment: A form is the specification for a set of fields and the rules for validating and cleaning associated data values.  The instance and/or "initial" arg provide default data values for each  field.  The form can also be constructed with an additional dictionary of data (e.g., usually POST data, but also GET or other data sources are possible).  The form's core purpose is to validate these data.  The fact that you render a form in HTML to collect data values from a user, or update the instance by saving the model form is convenience.